# NSTimer countdown producing 0 twice

Tags: swift, xcode, nstimer, date-format

I have some code that gets the difference of time between today and another time string.

The display is refreshed every second by using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`.

Everything is working fine except when the timer reaches 0. `0` is displayed twice.

Example:

```
3,2,1,0,0,-1,-2
```

[image]

Below is my code done done in playground:

```
   //: Playground - Time Countdown
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class MyClass {

    var totalSecondsText = ""

    init(classSecondsText: String){
        totalSecondsText = classSecondsText
    }

    @objc func ontimer(timer:NSTimer!){

        let total = determineTimeDifference(totalSecondsText)

                let (hour,min,sec) = secondsConverter(total)

                if hour >= 1 {
                    if min >= 1 {
                        NSLog(String(hour)+"h "+String(min)+"m")
                    }else {
                        NSLog(String(hour)+"h")
                    }
                }else{
                    if min >= 1{
                        NSLog(String(min)+"m "+String(sec)+"s")
                    } else if min > -1 {
                        NSLog(String(sec)+"s")
                    } else if min <= -1 {
                        NSLog(String(min)+"m")
                    }
                }
    }

    func determineTimeDifference(timeInputed: String) -> Int {

         let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
         dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
         let finalDate = dateFormat.dateFromString(raceTime)
         let differenceTimeInSeconds =  (finalDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow)!

    return differenceInSeconds

   }

    func secondsConverter (seconds : Int) -> (Int  , Int, Int){
        return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
    }

}

// Add +1 minute on time to test.
var dateString = "2016-08-31T6:49:00Z"

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: MyClass(classSecondsText: dateString), selector: #selector(MyClass.ontimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Any idea on what went wrong?

**Update:**

As promised, here is the bug fix for this issue:

```
    func determineTimeDifference(timeInputed: String) -> Int {

             let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
             dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
             let finalDate = dateFormat.dateFromString(raceTime)?.timeIntervalSince1970
             let dateNow = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
             let differenceTimeInSeconds = Int(finalDate) -  Int(dateNow)

     return differenceInSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is well provided, and conditions are placed correctly. 
It looks like `Data.components` is not handling counting difference correctly. It can be caused by rounding of seconds component.

If counting **before the moment, when current time and final time are equal**, (reach 0,0), result comes with an **error of -1**.

When I updated your code with additional prints, this was shown:

```
CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:10:57 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: 2s (BAD)
CURRENT unix: 1472649057.28685 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  -3.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
2s 

CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:10:58 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: 1s (BAD)
CURRENT unix: 1472649058.28734 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  -2.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
1s 

CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:10:59 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: 0s (BAD)
CURRENT unix: 1472649059.28731 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  -1.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
0s 

CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: 0s (OK)
CURRENT unix: 1472649060.28731 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  0.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
0s 

CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:11:01 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: -1s (OK)
CURRENT unix: 1472649061.28731 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  1.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
-1s 

CURRENT date: 2016-08-31 13:11:02 +0000 - FINAL date: 2016-08-31 13:11:00 +0000
-->> diff by DateComponents: -2s (OK)
CURRENT unix: 1472649062.28729 - FINAL unix: 1472649060.0
--->>> Diff in UNIX:  2.0s (counted as Rounded CURRENT UNIX - FINAL UNIX)
-2s
```

So if used counting by difference between rounded unix times, the results are correct.

Conclusion: The error sometimes comes before equation, sometimes comes after that. It depends on what time was that script launched. If counting by data components starts with an error, it cleans after 0, 0. If counting starts with correct result, then results start to bring error results. That's why zero appears twice - at the moment when result changes its precise status.

Comment: Thanks! Even-though i did not understand your explanation clearly (im a newbie in swift) It explained to me a lot. One more thing,  What do you mean by rounded unix times?

Comment: You are welcome. Rounded unix times means times in unix format, that comes with rounded value of snapped unix time cleaned from messy decimal part, that could possibly cause an error in counting. E.g. rounding of 1,459 would be 1, 1,668 => 2 etc. Perhaps, if Calendar component translates time, that has some part of .2873... in it, it counts it as whole second. So by rounding it we get rid of that possible error.

Comment: yeah pedrouan, I managed to update my code so that it will not display the double 0 anymore. thanks, I will update my question later so everyone can see the answer. Thanks again :D